# Move a file based on its contents

Tags: shell-script, awk, files

A directory receives lots of files throughout the day.
I only want to select and move the files according to the contents of line 2.
Here is what line 2 looks like:

```
L054   EL621306DEM-A0-AGI378-0001  70807 201708072017081100061542364673600268
```

- Condition 1: columns 8 & 9 = EL
- Condition 2: columns 42/43/44/45 = 2017

(using `ksh` on AIX 7.1)

Comment: The line, if interpreted as a space-delimited record, only contains four fields...

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools (GNU shell or other shell with support for ksh *process substitution* (`<(...)`), GNU `xargs` or compatible like FreeBSD's (for `-a`, `-r`, `-0`), GNU `mv` for `-t`, GNU `awk` for `nextfile` (also supported by some other implementations; it will be ignored but less efficient where not supported)):

```
xargs -r0a <(
  find dir -type f -exec awk 'FNR == 2 {
    if (substr($0, 8, 2) == "EL" && substr($0, 42, 4) == "2017")
      printf "%s\0", FILENAME
    nextfile}' {} +)  echo mv -it /somewhere
```

(remove `echo` if happy)

On non-GNU systems, you could change it to:

```
{
find dir -type f -exec awk -v q="'" '
  function quote_for_xargs(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    gsub("\n", q "\\\n" q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  FNR == 2 {
    if (substr($0, 8, 2) == "EL" && substr($0, 42, 4) == "2017")
      print quote_for_xargs(FILENAME)
    nextfile
  }' {} + | xargs sh -c '
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || exec echo mv -i "$@" /somewhere <&3 3<&-' sh
} 3<&0
```

(remove `echo` if happy).

That is have `find` call `awk` for every text file. In `awk`, for the second line of each file (`FNR==2`), if the conditions are met, print the file name is a format suitable for `xargs` (xargs input is treated as a list of words separated by blanks or newlines and where single and double quotes and backslashes can be used to escape the separators or each other). For instance, a file called `./That's tough.log` would be output as `'./That'\''s tough.log'`.

`xargs` takes that input to pass as many arguments as possible to `sh`. We need the `sh` wrapper because the destination directory has to be the last argument. We do want the `-i` because since the files end up in the same directory, there's scope for data to be lost if two files with the same name in different directories are being moved. We do need `mv`'s stdin (for the `-i` prompt) to *not* be the pipe from `find`, hence the use of a temporary fd 3 to forward the outer stdin to `sh` for `sh` to set `mv`'s stdin on that.

Comment: Yes, i mean character position. I have an error " syntax error at line 4 : `(' unexpected" ... an idea?

Comment: @Kiko, that assumes _GNU tools_. So including the GNU shell, `bash` (though it would work with `ksh` and `zsh` as well)

Comment: Sorry, AIX 7.1 platform

Comment: ksh shell is used

Comment: @Kiko, I'd have expected `<(...)` to work with `ksh` on AIX. But anyway, `xargs -r0a` or `mv -t` wouldn't have. See edit for a POSIX alternative.

Comment: I finally chose for a simpler traditional method ... find with exec and grep to list files in a text file. Then for, cat, do mv done ...